# How to use COUNTIFS with dynamic array returned by FILTER or SORT

Tags: microsoft-excel

The original function is

```
=COUNTIFS($A41:$ZZ41, ">3")
```

It works well.

But if I change it to:

```
=COUNTIFS(FILTER($A41:$ZZ41, $A41:$zz41=0), ">3")
```

Excel will raise a syntax error.

How can I use a dynamic array as `COUNTIFS`'s argument?

I know I can put filter criteria to countifs and avoid using filter, but this is just a example situation, the point is dynamic array not filter.

Comment: I can't see any obvious mistakes in your formula. Could you post also a screenshot of the formula & error message?

Comment: You can't do that directly. The `range` argument for the `COUNTIF` function has to be a **`range`**.  The `FILTER` function returns an array, hence your error.  You could put the filter function in a different range; then refer to that range in the `COUNTIF` function.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to accomplish, but wouldn't the wrapping formula be `count`?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld, `range` and `array` is confusing. For example, `SUM` function accept both `range` and `array`.

Comment: Yes, as do other functions.

Answer (score 0):

First the conditions are not correct for FILTER and COUNTIF.

Then you can change the formula to:

```
=COUNTIFS($A41:$ZZ41, ">3",$A41:$ZZ41,"=0")
```

But the result is **0**, your conditions are not correct.